# android resize webView

Tags: android, webview, resize

I want to create and resize a `WebView` in background, I will not show it or append it to a layout, I just want to create it, resize it and load things in background.
My problem is that even after resizing using `setLayoutParams` I'm getting **0** for `Height` and `Width`.
Here's what I did:

```
public void createAndResizeWebView(Context context) {

    WebView webView = new WebView(context);

    System.out.println("webView: " + webView.getWidth());
    System.out.println("webView: " + webView.getHeight());

    webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 400));

    System.out.println("webView: " + webView.getWidth());
    System.out.println("webView: " + webView.getHeight());
}
```

I get :

```
webView: 0

webView: 0

webView: 0

webView: 0
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout in android is asynchronous. Try overriding the WebView [onSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method to get notified when the webview's size changes. Alternatively you could also use a [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) but that's less efficient.

The WebView gets the size from it's view parent. Since you're not attaching the webview to a view it won't get sized at all and you need to force that by calling

```
webview.layout(0, 0, width, height);
```

note that the above is only one of the many methods that get called on the webview when it's in the view hierarchy. The implementation might change to depend on more/different calls in the future. A more future-proof way would be to insert the webview into your view hierarchy and set it's visibility to INVISIBLE.

Comment: `onSizeChanged` was never called. I can conclude that `webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 400));` did not change the size.

Comment: oh, yeath, duh! did you add the webview to the view system? you new it up but don't add it to any parent

Comment: I will not show it or append it to a layout, I just want to create it, resize it and load things in background.

Comment: @ElyesJlassi oh, sorry I missed that bit of your question. In that case you need to call webview.layout(0, 0, width, height) manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should print the width and height of the webView like this:

```
System.out.println("webView: " + webView.getLayoutParams().width);
System.out.println("webView: " + webView.getLayoutParams().height);
```